# calling systems setting Activity from service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I want to call android settings activity from service , i have use this code but it is not working .

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```

Comment: add this flag  `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);`

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and see what messages appear when it is "not working".

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary"); 
intent.setComponent(cn); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
startActivity( intent);
```